# Building tangobos to work with DMDScript / Getting ECMA Scripting to work with D1-Tango

Tags: javascript, d, tango, dmd

I'm trying to install [DMDScript-tango](http://hg.dsource.org/projects/dmdscript-tango/) on my win32 D1-Tango setup. The version I'm using is the [0.99.9 Kai bundle](http://www.dsource.org/projects/tango/wiki/TopicInstallTangoDmd) .

When I try building it, I get the following error (among others)

```
C:\DMD\sources\dmdscript>dsss build
Creating imports for dmdscript_tango

dmdscript_tango => dmdscript_tango
dmdscript_tango\script.d(24): module ctype cannot read file 'std\ctype.d'
Command c:\dmd\dsss\bin\rebuild.exe returned with code 1, aborting.
Error: Command failed, aborting.

C:\DMD\sources\dmdscript>
```

It looks like it still depends on some phobos code - But since the DMDScript source mentions tangobos, I figured I'd have to install it to make DMDScript work.

Judging from [what I've read](http://www.dsource.org/projects/tango/wiki/TangobosInfo), Tangobos seems to come bundled wih tango these days, but I can't seem to get it working. I'll have to assume that the page is outdated and tangobos does not in fact come with the 0.99.9 bundle.

So, I figured I'd grab the latest tangobos from svn.dsource.org, but when I try building it, I get this error:

```
C:\DMD\sources\tangobos>dsss build
Creating imports for crc32

Creating imports for tangobos

Creating imports for tangobos-etc

crc32.d => crc32
Error: no object files to link
Command c:\dmd\dsss\bin\rebuild.exe returned with code 1, aborting.
Error: Command failed, aborting.

C:\DMD\sources\tangobos>
```

I'm pretty clueless with those linker errors. So I can't figure out what to do to fix that one. [You can see the dsss.conf here](http://svn.dsource.org/projects/tangobos/trunk/dsss.conf).

So, my questions are:

1. Does anyone know what to do about that linker error?
2. Am I going around this the wrong way? Is there an easier way to install an ECMA/JavaScript scripting engine in D1?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Use D2.

Long answer: Use D2. D1 is now officially out of date, I'm not sure when it gets completely dropped, but they froze the development on it a while ago, and any new code (especially in Phobos) is being written against D2.

Tango-D1 is pretty much dead at the moment, with all the effort going towards SiegeLord's D2 port here: http://github.com/SiegeLord/Tango-D2. There have been no meaningful updates to Tango-D1 in months.

There is a port of DMDScript to D2 here: http://dsource.org/projects/dmdscript-2/. It says its complete, and the last commit was 5 months agi, so it seems legit, try it out.

Personally, I'd stick to D2 and Phobos for the time being, Tango-D2 is getting closer to done, and is aiming to be able to be installed alongside Phobos (so no weird conflicting druntimes). Try out the DMDScript-2 library on D2, and ask around the mailing list/forums for help ( http://forum.dlang.org/ ).

As a quick aside, D on windows is an experience most people find... lacking. This is a known problem, and hopefully will be rectified.

Comment: D on Windows is mostly fine, until you write programs large enough to break OPTLINK / statically link with less-portable C libraries / try writing 64-bit code.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm just going by the number of "Help I can't do xxx in windows" posts on the mailing lists.